# How can I maintain at the center an image using bootstrap 3.0

Tags: html, css

I'm using bootstrap 3.0 and for some reason I don't know, The image at the center keep moving when re-sizing the window, here is my html so far

```
    <div class="text-vertical-center">

        <img id="output" class="img-responsive img-center" src="http://s15.postimg.org/seg9dex3f/output2.png" alt="">
        <h3>This is some cool text</h3>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw fa-2x"></i>
        </button>


    </div>
</header>
```

And this is my CSS

```
#output{
display: table;
position: relative;
padding-left: 35%;


}
```

I had to put the padding at 35% because for default the image is all the way to the left, so with the 35% is centered in my "full screen window" but when re-sizing the image start to move because of this.

If some one could show me the way, I would appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: Use .col-*-* classes to give the image or div a width lower than 12 in the grid system and use .col-*-offset-* to move to the center or where you want for every screen sizes (xs, sm, md and lg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you use `display: table` on an *image* …?

Make that `display:block` instead, remove the `padding`, and add `margin: auto`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try also

```
#output{
  width:450px;
  max-width: 100%; 
  position: relative; 
  left: 50%; 
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%); 
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
```